# ERROR ORA-30483: window functions are not allowed here

Tags: sql

I tried to fech the Inventory Opening balance,Receipts ,Issues and Closing Balance SQL QUERY for all items and for year 2022 and particular organization but showing this error.
can anyone help me?

```
`SELECT 
  msi.inventory_item_id,
  msi.segment1 AS item_code,
  msi.description AS item_description,
  msi.primary_uom_code AS uom,
  NVL(sum(case when mmt.transaction_type_name in ('Receipt', 'Return to Vendor', 'Miscellaneous Receipt') then mmt.transaction_quantity else 0 end), 0) AS receipts,
  NVL(sum(case when mmt.transaction_type_name in ('Issue', 'Miscellaneous Issue') then -mmt.transaction_quantity else 0 end), 0) AS issues,
  NVL(SUM(mmt.transaction_quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY msi.inventory_item_id ORDER BY mmt.transaction_date, mmt.transaction_id) - 
      first_value(mmt.transaction_quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY msi.inventory_item_id ORDER BY mmt.transaction_date, mmt.transaction_id), 0) AS closing_balance,
  first_value(mmt.transaction_quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY msi.inventory_item_id ORDER BY mmt.transaction_date, mmt.transaction_id) AS opening_balance
FROM 
  mtl_system_items_b msi
  JOIN mtl_material_transactions mmt ON msi.inventory_item_id = mmt.inventory_item_id
  JOIN mtl_transaction_types_tl mtt ON mtt.transaction_type_id = mmt.transaction_type_id
  JOIN mtl_parameters mp ON mp.organization_id = mmt.organization_id
WHERE 
  mmt.transaction_date BETWEEN '01-JAN-2022' AND '31-DEC-2022'
  AND mp.organization_id = 3345 
GROUP BY 
  msi.inventory_item_id,
  msi.segment1,
  msi.description,
  msi.primary_uom_code,
  first_value(mmt.transaction_quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY msi.inventory_item_id ORDER BY mmt.transaction_date, mmt.transaction_id)
ORDER BY 
  msi.segment1`
```

Comment: Please add the related database tag

Comment: @Jens I am guessing [tag:oracle] based on error code _ORA-30483_

Comment: @Satpal It is better to know than guessing

Comment: Is really all that code needed to reproduce the error? Make it easy to assist you, minimize!

Answer (score 0):

Window functions are not allowed in GROUP BY.
See https://learnsql.com/blog/window-functions-not-allowed-group-by/